# Python,ftplib зависает при передаче данных на FTP сервер

Tags: python, linux, ftplib

Суть проблемы:
Есть проект на Python, живущий на linux-машине, у этого проекта есть модуль-демон, который отправляет некоторые файлы на ФТП с различной периодичностью. Все работает хорошо, пока проект запущен в терминальном режиме, файлы отправляются, все хорошо. Но как только запустить этот проект в фоновом режиме (при запуске машины он автоматически запускается), модуль перестает работать, виснет на создании файла на FTP. Ниже код модуля:

```
import ftplib
def send_files(host, ftp_user, ftp_password, *filenames):
    print('NEW REPORTING. MAIN BODY')
    print('NEW REPORTING. Filenames', filenames) 
    con = ftplib.FTP(host, ftp_user, ftp_password)
    print('NEW REPORTING. Connection opened')
    con.set_pasv(False)
    con.sendcmd('PASV')
    print('NEW REPORTING. Passive mode set')
    # Открываем файл для передачи в бинарном режиме
    con.cwd('/ftp')
    print('CWD DONE')
    for filename in filenames:
            filename = filename.split('/')[-1]
            print('NEW REPORTING. Working with', filename)
            f = open(filename, "rb")
            print('NEW REPORTING. File opened')
            # Передаем файл на сервер
            send = con.storbinary("STOR "+ filename, f)
            print('NEW REPORTING. File sent')
            # Закрываем FTP соединение
    con.close
    print('NEW REPORTING. Connection closed')
```

А вот это вырезка из syslog:

```
Aug 14 12:56:22 watchman python3[1436]: NEW REPORTING. MAIN BODY
Aug 14 12:56:22 watchman python3[1436]: NEW REPORTING. Filenames ('/home/watchman/watchman/new_rfid_log', '/home/watchman/watchman/record_test.xml', '/home/watchman/watchman/record_test_ext.xml')
Aug 14 12:56:22 watchman python3[1436]: NEW REPORTING. Connection opened
Aug 14 12:56:22 watchman python3[1436]: NEW REPORTING. Passive mode set
Aug 14 12:56:22 watchman python3[1436]: NEW REPORTING. Working with new_rfid_log
```

На этом софтина благополучно виснет и ничего дальше не происходит. FTP работает в пассивном режиме.

Comment: он точно виснет а не падает? как именно запускаешь его? systemd? если рестартить сервис, то он работает нормально?

Comment: Основной софт продолжает свою работу, а вот поток (запускаю через threading), который отправляет отчеты - виснет, он не падает, в логах нет traceback от python. Основной софт запускается с помощью systemd, после рестарта service, в логах ничего от софта не вижу (хотя в htop он есть), и клиент не может к нему подключиться (находится на другом ПК). Помогает reboot. Вообще даже после reboot, не сразу начинаю что то видеть от софта в syslog, хотя он работает нормально

Comment: гм... что-то у меня нет идей, почему открытие файла может виснуть... может оно всё же проваливается и исключение nb[j ловится где-то выше?

Comment: Спасибо, что указали правильное направление, отследил ошибку через systemctl status *runcore.service*

Answer (score 2):

Ответ найден! Проблема была в данном фрагменте кода:

```
   for filename in filenames:
        filename = filename.split('/')[-1]
        print('NEW REPORTING. Working with', filename)
        f = open(filename, "rb")
        print('NEW REPORTING. File opened')
        # Передаем файл на сервер
        send = con.storbinary("STOR "+ filename, f)
```

А именно в filename = filename.split('/')[-1]
При запуске программы через его родную директорию (где и хранились файлы для отправки), в терминальном режиме, она успешно находила все filenames и по filename.split('/')[-1] их отправляла. Но вот при запуске в виде сервиса, видимо, менялась текущая рабочая директория, поэтому просто по названию файла, без указания полного пути (filenames.split('/')[-1]), программа ничего не находила и успешно висла. Решил вот таким образом:

```
 for filename in filenames:
            f = open(filename, "rb")
            filename = filename.split('/')[-1]
            send = con.storbinary("STOR "+ filename, f)
```

Comment: Если `filename` это путь, то стоит использовать `pathlib`, а не сплитить строки. Также стоит файл `f` закрывать, наверное

Comment: @dIm0n, при уничтожении `f` в конце цикла он автомагически закрывается...

Comment: @Fat-Zer https://stackoverflow.com/q/1834556/13970074 и релейтеды

Comment: @dIm0n, мм... спасибо, интересно... никогда не углублялся в то, как в питоне работает сборщик мусора и всегда считал `with` простым сахаром...